# Proper format for NSDictionary keys for Coordinates

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

I have an `NSDictionary` that needs to store objects for a specific x/y coordinate. Because this is for an iOS (which is using both cocos2d and box2d), I already have to deal with different sets of coordinates being stored as `CGPoint` or `b2Vec2` - but I need something that can properly be used as the key of a dictionary.

One example I've seen combined the coords into an `NSString`, but that seems very inefficient to me. I used it as a temporary measure and sure enough, I see poor performance.

`NSString *coordKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f%f", coord.x, coord.y];`

I'm fine with writing a custom `NSCopying` object to hold the coordinates, but I'm wondering if that's really the best way...

- Is there an existing object I can use?
- Is a custom object considerably better than the dumb string formatting method
- Is there any way I can use the existing `b2Vec2` coordinate formats I already have some data in?

Comment: Have you tried with `NSValue`s? They should be able to hold `CGPoint`s

Answer (score 0):

I'd expect it to work if you define a coordinate class that holds `float32 x, y`, implements the `NSCopying` protocol, and implements a good `hash` method.

*However,* this hash table will retrieve an object only when queried at the exact same (x, y) coordinate. Relying on floating point equality is not good practice although it could work if the lookup key comes from enumerating a list of known values rather than doing some computation.

Consider using a [quadtree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree). That's a tree which organizes its contents by recursively subdividing into 4 quadrants.

Comment: I should probably mention that these coordinates are purely integers, not officially any need for floats.

Comment: Integers are better. If your key class stores `int x, y` then it won't be subject to floating point issues or performance costs, although the floating point issues are only a problem when the numbers exceed ±2^24. Two integers are easy to hash together, e.g. `7 + x * 3 + y * 5`.